# MediaCodec Fails To Dequeue Output on S9+

Tags: android-ndk, android-mediacodec

I have an Android plugin for Unity3D that decodes h264 video into a surface. This works on my S6 with Android 5.1.1. However, on my S9 running Android 8, output buffers are never dequeued.

My code for creating the decoder is straightforward:

```
codec = AMediaCodec_createDecoderByType ("video/avc");
AMediaFormat * format = AMediaFormat_new ();
AMediaFormat_setString (format, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_MIME, "video/avc");
AMediaFormat_setInt32 (format, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_WIDTH, 4096);
AMediaFormat_setInt32 (format, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_HEIGHT, 1536);
AMediaFormat_setInt32 (format, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_FRAME_RATE, 30);
AMediaCodec_configure (codec, format, window, NULL, 0);
AMediaCodec_start (codec);
AMediaFormat_delete (format);
```

Similarly, my code for queueing into the codec is relatively standard

```
ssize_t buffIdx = AMediaCodec_dequeueInputBuffer (codec, DequeueTimeoutUS);
if (buffIdx < 0)
    continue;
uint8_t* inputBuff = AMediaCodec_getInputBuffer (codec, buffIdx, &buffsize);
// I would copy into the input buffer here...
AMediaCodec_queueInputBuffer (codec, buffIdx, 0, copySize, pts, flags);
```

And my code for pulling from the decoder:

```
AMediaCodecBufferInfo info;
ssize_t status = AMediaCodec_dequeueOutputBuffer (codec, &info, DequeueOutputTimeout);
if (status == AMEDIACODEC_INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER)
    continue;
// I would update the surface texture here...
AMediaCodec_releaseOutputBuffer (codec, status, info.size != 0);
```

Unfortunately, dequeueing only returns AMEDIACODEC_INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER. Here are the logs from it running on the S9+

```
 02-14 15:00:50.346  8005  8158 I ACodec  :  [] Now uninitialized
 02-14 15:00:50.347  8005  8160 I ACodec  : [] onAllocateComponent
 02-14 15:00:50.353  8005  8160 I OMXClient: Treble IOmx obtained
 02-14 15:00:50.353  8005  8160 I ACodec  : Set Google AAC Dec for aacProfile 0
 02-14 15:00:50.357  2692  7767 I OMXMaster: makeComponentInstance(OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc) in omx@1.0-service process
 02-14 15:00:50.359   684   684 I android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service: getLinkLayerStats
 02-14 15:00:50.365  2692  7767 E         : Service not available yet
 02-14 15:00:50.388  2692  7767 I OMX-VDEC-1080P: Video slvp perflock acquired
 02-14 15:00:50.389  2692  7767 I OMX-VDEC-1080P: component_init: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc : fd=22
 02-14 15:00:50.389  2692  7767 E OMX-VDEC-1080P: Unsupported output color format for c2d (2141391876)
 02-14 15:00:50.389  2692  7767 E OMX-VDEC-1080P: Setting color format failed
 02-14 15:00:50.396  2692  7767 I OMX-VDEC-1080P: omx_vdec::component_init() success : fd=22
 02-14 15:00:50.397  8005  8160 I ACodec  : [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] Now Loaded
 02-14 15:00:51.818  8005  8159 D SurfaceUtils: connecting to surface 0xc4b86808, reason connectToSurface
 02-14 15:00:51.818  8005  8159 I MediaCodec: [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] setting surface generation to 8197121
 02-14 15:00:51.818  8005  8159 D SurfaceUtils: disconnecting from surface 0xc4b86808, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
 02-14 15:00:51.818  8005  8159 D SurfaceUtils: connecting to surface 0xc4b86808, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
 02-14 15:00:51.819  2687 32660 I ResourceManagerService: ResourceManagerService checkCodecCapacity pid 8005 clientId 3218327712 useExtended 0
 02-14 15:00:51.820  8005  8160 I ACodec  : [HW_HDR] HDR-OFF 0
 02-14 15:00:51.820  8005  8160 W DirectStreamingProxy: app-pid not found. use getpid(). pid = 8005
 02-14 15:00:51.821  8005  8160 D DirectStreamingProxy: pid = 8005
 02-14 15:00:51.823  2692  7767 E OMX-VDEC-1080P: Enable/Disable allocate-native-handle allowed only on input port!
 02-14 15:00:51.823  2692  7767 E OMX-VDEC-1080P: set_parameter: Error: 0x80001019, setting param 0x7f00005d
 02-14 15:00:51.823  2692  7767 E OMXNodeInstance: setParameter(0xee709444:qcom.decoder.avc, OMX.google.android.index.allocateNativeHandle(0x7f00005d): Output:1 en=0) ERROR: UnsupportedSetting(0x80001019)
 02-14 15:00:51.823  2692  7767 E OMX-VDEC-1080P: Extension: OMX.google.android.index.storeANWBufferInMetadata not implemented
 02-14 15:00:51.824  8005  8160 I ACodec  : [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] OMX_QCOM_FramePacking_OnlyOneCompleteFrame is setting
 02-14 15:00:51.824  2676  3409 V APM_AudioPolicyManager:   getOutputForDevice() returns output 29
 02-14 15:00:51.824  2692  7767 E OMX-VDEC-1080P: Extension: OMX.google.android.index.storeANWBufferInMetadata not implemented
 02-14 15:00:51.824  2692  7767 E OMX-VDEC-1080P: Extension: OMX.google.android.index.configureVideoTunnelMode not implemented
 02-14 15:00:51.824  2692  7767 E OMX-VDEC-1080P: Extension: OMX.google.android.index.useAndroidNativeBuffer is supported
 02-14 15:00:51.824  2692  7767 E OMX-VDEC-1080P: Setparameter: unknown param 2130706434
 02-14 15:00:51.824  2692  7767 E OMX-VDEC-1080P: set_parameter: Error: 0x8000101a, setting param 0x7f000002
 02-14 15:00:51.824  2692  7767 E OMXNodeInstance: setParameter(0xee709444:qcom.decoder.avc, ??(0x7f000002)) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
 02-14 15:00:51.824  8005  8160 W ACodec  : Fail to set FramePackingMode(-1010)
 02-14 15:00:51.824  2676  3409 I AudioFlinger: add dynamic flag, can move to deep thread, session 601
 02-14 15:00:51.824  8005  8160 I ExtendedACodec: setupVideoDecoder()
 02-14 15:00:51.828  8005  8160 I ExtendedACodec: Decoder will be in frame by frame mode
 02-14 15:00:51.828  2692  2845 E OMX-VDEC-1080P: Setparameter: unknown param 2130706434
 02-14 15:00:51.828  2692  2845 E OMX-VDEC-1080P: set_parameter: Error: 0x8000101a, setting param 0x7f000002
 02-14 15:00:51.828  2692  2845 E OMXNodeInstance: setParameter(0xee709444:qcom.decoder.avc, ??(0x7f000002)) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
 02-14 15:00:51.828  8005  8160 W ExtendedACodec: Failed to set frame packing format on component
 02-14 15:00:51.828  8005  8160 I SmartFittingClass: Create SmartFitting Version 2.0
 02-14 15:00:51.830  2689  2887 I RemoteDisplayService: There is no RemoteDisplay
 02-14 15:00:51.831  8005  8160 I SmartFittingClass: Init, [State:UNINITIALIZED] pid: 8005
 02-14 15:00:51.832  3051  3365 D CodecSolution: setSmartFittingPid : 8005
 02-14 15:00:51.833  3051  3365 D CodecSolution: setSmartFittingMode : 0
 02-14 15:00:51.833  3051  3434 D CodecSolution: handleMessage : 202
 02-14 15:00:51.836  2692  7768 E OMX-VDEC-1080P: Does not handle dataspace request
 02-14 15:00:51.836  2692  7768 E OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xee709444:qcom.decoder.avc, ??(0x7f000062)) ERROR: UnsupportedSetting(0x80001019)
 02-14 15:00:51.845  8005  8160 I ACodec  : [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] Now Loaded->Idle
 02-14 15:00:51.858  2692  2900 E OMX-VDEC-1080P: Extension: OMX.google.android.index.AndroidNativeBufferConsumerUsage not implemented
 02-14 15:00:51.858  8005  8160 D SurfaceUtils: set up nativeWindow 0xc4b86808 for 4096x1536, color 0x7fa30c06, rotation 0, usage 0x20402900
 02-14 15:00:51.859  8005  8160 I ACodec  : [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] configureOutputBuffersFromNativeWindow setBufferCount :17, minUndequeuedBuffers : 5
 02-14 15:00:51.860  3051  3365 W CodecSolution: PackageInfo is null.
 02-14 15:00:51.860  8005  8175 I SmartFittingClass: InitialCheck, WhiteListStatus returned from CodecSolution : 0
 02-14 15:00:51.860  8005  8175 I SmartFittingClass: InitialCheck, 
 02-14 15:00:51.864  3051  3365 D CodecSolution: reportMediaStatisticsEvent: action=1@1986621044;category=2@1986621044;label=1936222260@1986621044
 02-14 15:00:51.864  3051  3365 D MediaStatisticsEvent: MediaStatisticsEvent: action=1@1986621044;category=2@1986621044;label=1936222260@1986621044
 02-14 15:00:51.864  3051  3365 D MediaStatisticsEvent: Category.valueOf: 2
 02-14 15:00:51.864  3051  3365 D MediaStatisticsEvent: Action.valueOf: 1
 02-14 15:00:51.864  3051  3365 D MediaStatisticsEvent: Label.valueOf: 0x73686834
 02-14 15:00:51.864  3051  3365 D MediaStatisticsEvent: category: VDEC
 02-14 15:00:51.864  3051  3365 D MediaStatisticsEvent: action: INSTANTIATE
 02-14 15:00:51.864  3051  3365 D MediaStatisticsEvent: label: SEC_HW_H264
 02-14 15:00:51.865  3051  3434 D CodecSolution: handleMessage : 900
 02-14 15:00:51.865  3051  3434 D CodecSolution: event : VDEC
 02-14 15:00:51.865  3051  3434 D Logging : appId: com.samsung.android.codecsolution, feature: VDEC, extra: SEC_HW_H264, value: -1
 02-14 15:00:51.865  2687  1137 I ResourceManagerService: addMediaInfo -(PID : 8005, clientID : 3218327712)
 02-14 15:00:51.865  2687  1137 I ResourceManagerService: MediaInfo add 6291456 (width 4096 height 1536) remained 11403264
 02-14 15:00:51.865  2687  1137 I ResourceManagerService: getMediaResourceInfo resourceType : 2, size : 1
 02-14 15:00:51.865  2687  1137 I ResourceManagerService: getMediaResourceInfo (PID : 8005, clientID : 3218327712, non-secure-codec/video-codec:1, 4096x1536(fps:30) - SoftCodec : No, Encorder : No)
 02-14 15:00:51.865  3051  3365 V ResourceManagerHelper-JNI: JNIMediaResourceHelper::notify eventType : 1, ext1 : 0, ext2 : 0
 02-14 15:00:51.865  3051  3365 V ResourceManagerHelper-JNI: notify eventType : 1, ext1 : 0, ext2 : 0
 02-14 15:00:51.865  8005  8160 I ACodec  : [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] Now Idle->Executing
 02-14 15:00:51.866  3051  3365 I SemMediaResourceHelper: makeMediaResourceInfo mOwnResourceEventExcluded : false, mPid : 3051
 02-14 15:00:51.866  3051  3365 I SemMediaResourceHelper: [1] makeMediaResourceInfo resourceType : 2 isSecured : false, pid : 8005, client id : 3218327712
02-14 15:00:51.866  8005  8160 I ACodec  : [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] Now Executing
02-14 15:00:51.870  8005  8160 W GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
```

The last line about invalid usage bits repeats roughly in-step with me queueing the input buffers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was because I was incidentally flagging every buffer with BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG. Only adding that flag for the first input buffer fixed the issue.

Comment: Could you please elaborate this answer. I am facing same kind of issue with MediaEncoders which used to stream data to YouTube using RTMP in Android. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I don't know what you specifically want me to elaborate on, if you have a more specific question then I can maybe answer that